# Getting data from query string and displaying it on a label on the clientside

Tags: asp.net, html, label, query-string, client-side

I have this issue when I change a small bit of text in a label based on the query string. what I am currently trying is

`Text = "after 30 June "'<%=Request.QueryString ("Year")%>'"` in the comments field"

and getting the following error

> 'System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString' cannot be used like a method.

Any help would be much appreciated..

Cheers,

Comment: check the new answer i posted according to ur comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the **asp:Label**, I just made use of the default **HTML Label tag** which allows me to add <%=Request.QueryString["Year"]%> any where between the text.

Answer (score 1):

ok according to ur comment i am writing this new code
First Take all your labels in array for which you want to set dynamic text

```
var labels = ["<%=label1.ClientID%>", "<%=label2.ClientID%>", "<%=label3.ClientID%>", "<%=label4.ClientID%>", "<%=label5.ClientID%>"];
```

then write this function

```
function ForLabel(){
var year= '<%= Request.QueryString["Year"]%>';
var labels = ["<%=label1.ClientID%>", "<%=label2.ClientID%>", "<%=label3.ClientID%>", "<%=label4.ClientID%>", "<%=label5.ClientID%>"];
AddDynamicTextToLabel(labels,year);
}
```

then call this below function in ForLabel Function

```
 function AddDynamicTextToLabel(labels,year){

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        Elem = document.getElementById(labels[i]);
Elem.Value=Elem.Value+year;

       }
        }
```

call the function ForLabel in page load

```
 function pageLoad() {
ForLabel();
                  }
```

Comment: Hey Mate, That is an interesting way of doing it but I found a simpler solution. Instead of using the <asp:Label></asp:Label>, I just made use of the <Label></Label> which allows me to add <%=Request.QueryString["Year"]%> any where between the text. anyways thanks for helping me out man, really appreciate it.

Comment: you are always welcome vikram,if u r using html label then you can modify my answer by removing the clientID from <%=label1.ClientID%>,

Comment: you can post your answer if you want

Answer (score 0):

Since you have said that you want to set lable text on client side then you have to write the following code

```
var label = document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID%>");

var year= '<%= Request.QueryString["Year"]%>';

label.value="after 30 June "+year;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Anuj. This solution defeats the purpose, as in I dont want to reassign the label text cause I have several other labels within the page where i Dynamically want to change the year alone.

Comment: your problem didnt get solved by the solution i provided?what exactly you require be more precise so that i can give you exact solution for your problem

Comment: well basically I have multiple labels within the page where currently I am defining the year as static text and I want to make it dynamic based on the query string that i have. Problem is the label has a series of characters in the text attribute in which i only want the year to be dynamic example would be one where i posted the actual question.

Comment: ok i got ur point an i have posted another answer just check if it helps